# Isuues after converting project from java to kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, code-conversion

Hello there after a long time thinking about converting my project from java to kotlin , today I shift from java to kotlin , and as expected and warned by the community that the project will not magically just transfer everything easily to kotlin, there are errors now

ok I just make it clear I'm a very beginner in kotlin but I was somewhat familiar with java

there are as I noticed 1 main error with almost all the converted java to kotlin files

```
Smart cast to 'RecyclerView!' is impossible, because 'postRecyclerView' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time
```

in java, for eg if I have to add a scroll listener I just do this

```
recyclerview.addOnScrollListner
```

but getting error in kotlin // below is lines are kotlin

```
postRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(
            staggeredGridLayoutManager
        )
```

or

```
 postRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener
```

or

```
shimmerFrameLayout.startShimmer()
```

as I don't know much about kotlin I don't know what it is

and secondly, in my old java adapter class, I have

```
public static List<Upload> mUploads;
```

but now as converted in kotlin I'm facing an issue with mUploads
for eg on this line

```
val uploadCurrent: Upload = Companion.mUploads.get(position)
```

getting error on mUploads it is showing Unresolved reference: mUploads

Old java adapter class code

**PostAdapter_Home.java**

```
public class PostAdapter_Home extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter_Home.PostViewHolder> {
    public static List<Upload> mUploads;
    public Context mcontext;

    public PostAdapter_Home(Context context, List<Upload> uploads) {
        mUploads = uploads;
        mcontext = context;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        view = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext).inflate(R.layout.ex_home, parent, false);
        return new PostViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Shimmer shimmer = new Shimmer.ColorHighlightBuilder()
                .setBaseColor(Color.parseColor("#F3F3F3"))
                .setBaseAlpha(1)
                .setHighlightColor(Color.parseColor("#E7E7E7"))
                .setHighlightAlpha(1)
                .setDropoff(50)
                .build();
        ShimmerDrawable shimmerDrawable = new ShimmerDrawable();
        shimmerDrawable.setShimmer(shimmer);
        Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
        Glide.with(mcontext)
                .load(uploadCurrent.getmImageUrl())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
                .placeholder(shimmerDrawable)
                .centerCrop()
                .fitCenter()
                .into(holder.imageView);

//        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(view -> changeScaleType(holder, position));

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUploads.size();
    }

    public void setUploads(List<Upload> uploads){
        mUploads=uploads;
    }
    public static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final ShapeableImageView imageView;

        public PostViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagePostHome);

        }


    }
}
```

**PostAdapter.kt**

```
class PostAdapter     /* ShimmerFrameLayout shimmerFrameLayout; */(
    var mcontext: Context
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostViewHolder>() {
    private var mListener: OnItemClickListener? = null
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PostViewHolder {
        LayoutInflater.from(mcontext).inflate(R.layout.post_item_container_profile, parent, false)
        val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.post_item_container_profile, parent, false)
        return PostViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PostViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val uploadCurrent: Upload? = mUploads.get(position)
        val shimmer = ColorHighlightBuilder()
            .setBaseColor(Color.parseColor("#F3F3F3"))
            .setBaseAlpha(1f)
            .setHighlightColor(Color.parseColor("#E7E7E7"))
            .setHighlightAlpha(1f)
            .setDropoff(50f)
            .build()
        val shimmerDrawable = ShimmerDrawable()
        shimmerDrawable.setShimmer(shimmer)
        Glide.with(mcontext)
            .load(uploadCurrent.getmImageUrl())
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
            .placeholder(shimmerDrawable)
            .centerCrop()
            .fitCenter()
            .into(holder.imageView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return Companion.mUploads.size
    }

    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: OnItemClickListener?) {
        mListener = listener
    }

    fun setUploads(uploads: List<Upload>) {
        Companion.mUploads = uploads
    }

    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onClick(view: View?)
        fun onItemClick(position: Int)
        fun onDeleteClick(position: Int)
    }

    inner class PostViewHolder internal constructor(itemView: View) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener, OnCreateContextMenuListener,
        MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener {
        var imageView: ShapeableImageView
        override fun onClick(v: View) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                val position = adapterPosition
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    mListener!!.onItemClick(position)
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onCreateContextMenu(menu: ContextMenu, v: View, menuInfo: ContextMenuInfo) {
            val delete = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 2, 2, "Delete")
            delete.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onMenuItemClick(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
            if (mListener != null) {
                val position = adapterPosition
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    if (item.itemId == 2) {
                        mListener!!.onDeleteClick(position)
                        return true
                    }
                }
            }
            return false
        }

        init {
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagePost)
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
            itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this)
        }
    }

    companion object
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have `mUploads` as a static variable in the first place. Mutable statics should be avoided unless you need to hold some global state for your entire app. Also, if you're using Hungarian notation, you should prefix static variables with `s` instead of `m`. I'm not a fan of Hungarian notation personally, but why use it at all if you aren't going to take advantage of what it actually means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because in kotlin, There're **two ways to declare variables.

Using **lateinit** keyword : no need to initialize while declaration.

Using **null** as initial value for variable.

So when you converted java files to kotlin it may have initialized your values with **null**
So you can add  **!!** or **?** operator at end of variable for null safety which is initialized as null.

example.

```
postRecyclerView!!.setLayoutManager(
            staggeredGridLayoutManager
        )
 postRecyclerView!!.addOnScrollListener
```

for more you can check this link
[Null Safety Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#nullable-types-and-non-null-types)

In kotlin, static variables (Which can be accessed only with class name) are under companion object blocks

```
   companion object{
    //your variables here
    }
```

As you're using mUploads inside same class, You don't need to access it with class name.
Use

```
mUploads.get(position)
```

instead of

```
Companion.mUploads.get(position)
```

Comment: ok but what do i do with this  fun setUploads(uploads: List<Upload>) {
        Companion.mUploads = uploads
    }  ,, it says Unresolved reference: mUploads

Comment: or in  this ,,  override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return Companion.mUploads.size
    }

Comment: and thank you so much for the answer, actually, I'm worried about the kotlin community support on SO because kotlin is newer compared to java so i don't how the support is for kotlin but now , this is a good beginning for the support

Comment: @VasantRaval You know, static variables can be accessed only inside static methods.
You can move mUploads out of companion object block.  Also in Adapter constructor, use val  keyword so that you can access it inside class and inside nested class under PostAdapter_Home . Can you show me your kotlin adapter class for the same ?

Comment: I have updated the question with the kotlin adapter class please can you check it

Comment: @VasantRaval  Update PostAdapter constructor like this, 
  class PostAdapter     /* ShimmerFrameLayout shimmerFrameLayout; */(
    var mcontext: Context,
val mUploads:List<Upload>
)

Then you will need to pass list directly where you have created adapter. Then you don't need to anything, remove Companion  from there. 
Also if you need more help can you connnect with me ?

Comment: there is an error in fragment class on lines with Objectrequired not null like for eg                              "Objects.requireNonNull(upload).setmKey(dataSnapshot.key)" after (upload). there is an error that says Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Upload? but if I add " ? or !! " the error gets resolved but there is a warning that says there should be  " . " instead of  "? or !!"